# why it is hard to generate an impulse train ?

Tags: communication, sampling

I have understood the concept of Ideal impulse sampling ,but i have struck upon the fact that practically generation of impulse train is not possible.

Comment: Yes, an ideal impulse train is not phsically realisable. In practice, impulses of short duration compared to the fastest time constant in the system under investigation suffice. Generally, an impulse is not a very friendly deterministic input - hitting a system with a hammer can be harmful.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible because a voltage step with infinitely fast rise times and fall times is impossible. Any small but finite amount of capacitance connected to the wire that produces the impule will take an infinite current and this is not possible: -

I = C dv/dt governs this.

Comment: +1 - the breakthrough I had was realizing that everything is a capacitor.

Comment: Yup, everything is a capacitor!